# Add event to body only one time

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change the follow line to add the handler only one time

```
$('body').on('click.collapse.data-api', '[data-toggle=collapse]', function ( e ) {
})
```

My idea is to add an attribute to the element after add the bind for the first time and, check if the element has the attribute before adding the bind.

To set the attribute is easy:

```
$('body').find('[data-toggle=collapse]').attr('data-loaded',"true");
```

But to change the selector to check if the attribute is not set is the hard part.

I tried something like:

```
$('body').on('click.collapse.data-api', '[data-toggle=collapse] :not([data-loaded])',function ( e ) {
})
```

but it doesn't work...

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just take a wild guess ?

```
$('body').on('click', '.collapse.data-api[data-toggle="collapse"]', function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).data('loaded')) $(e.target).attr('data-loaded', true);
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ukBnP/)

Comment: This way,click only works the first time. I need to bind only once, not click only one time. :(

Comment: Why would someone bind an event handler twice? and why are you even mentioning "only one time" in your question ? Anyway, edited the answer, which again is just a wild guess as it's hard to understand what it is you're after ?

Comment: I don't want to bind an event twice. This was only a fail-safe to try to disallow unintentional duplicated binding. But I end up not using this approach. Thanks for trying to answer.